# Recreating a striped ball on a striped background

Tags: plotting

I want to recreate the following image, which resembles the cover of a music album [*Circle 2: Gathering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_2:_Gathering).

How can I do this using Mathematica?

[image: img1]

Comment: This already looks like it was made in Mathematica judging by the plot colours and the tick marks down the right hand side, so there might already be code out there to generate this. Where did you get it?

Comment: @flinty A chat software similar to Telegram. But there is no accompanying code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The idea is that at first draw a 3D sphere `x^2 + y^2 +z^2==r^2` and using `z==0` to cut it off, that is `Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 - y^2]`.
- After that we use a series of paralle planes with `normal={a,b,c}` to cut such hemisphere and `z==0` synchronously to get the meshs.
  `MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} . {a, b, c}]`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
normal = {a, b, c} = {-3, 4, 5};
r = 4;
Plot3D[Boole[r^2 - x^2 - y^2 >= 0]  Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, -5, 5}, ViewPoint -> Top, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 Mesh -> 40, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} . {a, b, c}], 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 MeshStyle -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

- `ContourPlot` for 2D.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
normal = {a, b, c} = {-3, 4, 5};
r = 4;
ContourPlot[
 Boole[r^2 - x^2 - y^2 >= 0]    Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> 40, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} . {a, b, c}], 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 Contours -> {-1}, ContourShading -> None, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["`*"]; ContourPlot[
 Cos[x - y - 
    Sqrt[Max[20^2 - (x^2 + y^2), 0]]] == 0, {x, -21, 
  21}, {y, -21, 21}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: img1]

Related [posts](https://twitter.com/TETH_Main/status/1626428717290627074).